# Can records be copied in libreoffice base

Tags: libreoffice-base

Running version 5.2.2.2 of LibreOffice on linux.

I'm evaluating a replacement for using the MS-Access front-end to a Postgres table backend, primarily because Microsoft seems to be itching to EOL Access.  I read that LibreOffice Base is a good alternative and indeed, it appears to be in all but one respect.  In the table/spreadsheet style interface, I can't seem to copy a record in the table to the end of the table where I would then make changes (to avoid primary key violations).

I've googled around and it looks like I'm not the first to hit this.  It's surprising because one would think this would be a pretty basic thing one would want to do/support.  One guy wrote a macro to do this.  But calling the macro wojuld have to be via clicking a button in a form.  We don't want to use forms or click buttons, so I'm frowning on that one.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way around this hole, preferably by doing something intuitive like ^c to copy and ^v to paste on an empty line at the bottom of the table . We're running 5.2.2.2 .  Did they support this in later versions ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Update:  I got a hold of 7.0.1.2 .  Same problem :-(

Comment: "One guy wrote a macro to do this." - Could you provide a link?

Answer (score 1):

The table data view does not have a lot of features. What you want can be done in various ways with forms, for example with a table control. But since you explicitly do not want forms, here is one way that should work. This macro code is in Python-UNO, but it could be adapted to LO Basic or Java.

```py
from com.sun.star.datatransfer import DataFlavor, UnsupportedFlavorException

oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
ctx = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getComponentContext()
oClip = ctx.getServiceManager().createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.datatransfer.clipboard.SystemClipboard", ctx)
transferable = oClip.getContents()
dataFlavors = transferable.getTransferDataFlavors()
df = DataFlavor()
df.HumanPresentableName = "Data source Table"
df.MimeType = (
    'application/x-openoffice-dbaccess-table;'
    'windows_formatname="Data source Table"')
try:
    data = transferable.getTransferData(df)
    props = data
    for prop in props:
        if prop.Name == "Cursor":
            resultSet = prop.Value
            rownum = resultSet.Row
except UnsupportedFlavorException:
    msgbox("Clipboard does not have data of type {0}.".format(
        df.HumanPresentableName))
```

The idea is to copy a row and then run the macro to create the new row, for example by binding it to a hotkey of your choice. The `resultSet` object contains all of the information needed to get the data of the copied row. Use an introspection tool such as MRI to display the object properties and methods. You would then need to write code to insert a new record in the same table with these values, except create a different primary key.

As a reference for this answer I found a PDF at [https://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jlop/chaps/43.%20Using%20the%20Clipboard.pdf](https://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/%7Ead/jlop/chaps/43.%20Using%20the%20Clipboard.pdf) that has quite a bit of useful information, including a section specifically for Base. This is very advanced macro coding though. As suggested earlier, the normal solution would be to use forms, and even that may not be particularly easy, as Base macros are typically more difficult than Writer or Calc macros.

One more idea: have you tried pgAdmin to see if it does what you need? It can edit table data if I recall correctly.

Be sure to post on the AskLO forum as well, with a link to this question. Ratslinger over there is an expert at all things Base.

**EDIT**:

> I thought forms could on;y handle one record at a time.

Not at all. The form wizard can create a table control which displays all records. The 5th wizard step says "Arrange the controls on your form" which it looks like is where the table control is chosen. For me, table control was the default.

Forms are built on recordsets, with a single primary record active, similar to the table data view. The primary record can be linked to other records, tables and queries all in a single form. In your case, it sounds like all you need is to work with a single table, so that should be pretty simple.

The wizard is limited and doesn't generate very good forms. So what I often do is use the wizard to create a starter form and then use the form design view and form navigator to delete most of what it created and add tables and controls in my own choice of structure / relationships, editing the controls to specify SQL or fields that tell how the form data is connected.

Comment: Thanks You Jim for the answer and the code.
" What you want can be done in various ways with forms, for example with a table control. "     I'm intrigued !  Could you give me a high level approach to this ?   I thought forms could on;y handle one record at a time.